# plugin_dir_url() adds path to url

Tags: plugin-development, plugins-url

For some reason I get the following output from

```
var_dump( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
```

> http://local.dev/wp-content/plugins/C:/development/xampp/htdocs/vanilla/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/

in a local install.

<sup>Note: I deactivated **all** plugins and added the line on top of the `functions.php` file of the default and unmodified TwentyEleven Theme</sup>

Comment: Perhaps it's confused because the file isn't in the plug-ins directory? It probably finds the 'relative' path to it to append onto the plugin-url, in this case the 'relative' path is  an absolute one, because it couldn't it in the directory (a dodgy fallback...?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`plugin_basename()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename) call some levels inside which seems to use `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` constants, so my guess would be this function is only meant to be used for things inside plugin directories and not other places like theme.

Comment: So the only chance left is to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/path/to/some/file.ext;`?

Comment: @kaiser that would be my idea for use in theme.

Comment: Rarst beat me to it - and I totally missed that @Kaiser was calling this from within a Theme.